# synchronization lock text field for php

Tags: php, html

How to lock a text field when one user typing in one text field??
Means that when 1 user typing in the text field, other user unable to type in that particular text field.. Is there a way to do that??

Comment: Same page, multiple users? or multiple clients?

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, you'll need to use JavaScript to constantly poll the server for changes. When a user starts typing, he'll Ajax the server notifying it of that. The server will save the new state to the database, and when the rest of the users poll for changes, the server will tell them user X is editing field Y, and use JavaScript to lock the field.

Note that this method shouldn't be used for critical security features! A user can easily bypass anything made in JavaScript, or on the client-side in general. You should validate on the server side as well, and not accept input on a field which is already being typed in.

Comment: is there any other ways like using HTML5 feature?? I think i cant use javascript in here since it will caused critical issue in my application. i saw that PHP got provide some function like sem_acquire to lock and release it. But i still got no idea how to do the synchronization lock.